# what is the collision of rand.Read

Tags: go, mattermost

I have encountered two problems while browsing mattermost code

1. Why the length of `data []byte` is `1+(length*5/8)`? why is `length` multiplied by 5?
2. what is the collision of `rand.Read`? on Linux and FreeBSD, `rand.Read` uses getrandom(2) if available

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/base32"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    fmt.Println(NewRandomString(64))
}

var encoding = base32.NewEncoding("ybndrfg8ejkmcpqxot1uwisza345h769")

// NewRandomString returns a random string of the given length.
// The resulting entropy will be (5 * length) bits.
func NewRandomString(length int) string {
    data := make([]byte, 1+(length*5/8))
    rand.Read(data)
    return encoding.EncodeToString(data)[:length]
}
```

you can try: https://play.golang.org/p/WcS667bP407

refer to https://github.com/mattermost/mattermost-server/blob/fc60a1e8dd9d1a225687aead0684035ee63d7562/model/utils.go#L184

Comment: "what is the collision of rand.Read?" What do you mean by "collision"?

Comment: @Volker probability of generating the same string

Comment: rand.Read reads 0 to k bytes. The collision probability if it read n bytes is 2^(-n). The question makes no sense whatsoever. crypto/rand is suitable for cryptographic use and that's all there is to know. If you create a single random byte, even from a totally undeterministic, random, equally distributed random source your collision probability will be 0.39% but that's because you generated just 8 bits of "randomness"

Comment: Considering that we use that same function to generate UUIDs, and UUIDs are much smaller than 320 bits, the probability of a collision should be zero, for all intents and purposes. It's not, technically, but if you're looking for an academic answer this isn't the right forum. Have you searched on security.stackexchange.com yet?

Comment: I have searched, found this https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key/3939#3939, I only know that his probability is low, but I don't know exactly how low

Comment: @jk2K exactly how low depends on context.  Data collisions occur in data systems.  What system are we talking about?

Comment: the random string is used to create a token to verify email. length is `64`, this means that the token consists of 64 characters

Answer (score 5):

Because it's returning a base32 string, and each character of a base32 string holds 5 bits of information. So e.g. if you want to generate a 40-character base32 string, you need 200 bits of randomness, which is achieved by reading 25 (that is, 200 / 8) random bytes.